# PubNub delay to receive message from subscribed channel (Android)

Tags: android, pubnub

I'm integrating Android SDK into my app and following this tutorial to subscribe and publish message to channel: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/android-java/data-streams-publish-and-subscribe

When it just connect to and subscribe to channel it can receive the message from subscribed channel immediately but if I leave that in some minutes, I cannot get message anymore and for sometimes late the message will reach.

I use method successCallback(String channel, Object message) to receive and handle message. So do anyone got that problem like me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems that you use an outdated SDK version. Try with the latest one `4.3.0`

I implement it simply like that

```
 PNConfiguration pnConfiguration = new PNConfiguration();
        pnConfiguration.setSubscribeKey(youKey);
        pnConfiguration.setReconnectionPolicy(PNReconnectionPolicy.LINEAR);

        pubnub = new PubNub(pnConfiguration);
        pubnub.addListener(this);
        pubnub.subscribe()
            .channels(Arrays.asList(channel))
            .execute();
```

`PNReconnectionPolicy.LINEAR` is useful to automatically reconnect and receive message when you're disconnected (and it's happens a lot)

then my class implement `SubscribeCallback` with the following :

```
@Override
public void unsubscribeAndDisconnect() {
    pubnub.destroy();
}


@Override
public void status(PubNub pubnub, PNStatus status) {
    switch (status.getCategory()) {
        case PNConnectedCategory:
            logger.debug("Pubnub Connected");
            break;
        case PNReconnectedCategory:
            logger.debug("Pubnub reconnected");
            break;
        case PNDisconnectedCategory:
            logger.debug("Pubnub disconnected");
            break;
        case PNUnexpectedDisconnectCategory:
            logger.debug("Pubnub Unexcpected disconnect");
            pubnub.reconnect();
            break;
        case PNTimeoutCategory:
            logger.debug("Pubnub Timeout");
            pubnub.reconnect();
            break;
        default:
            logger.debug("Pubnub " + status.getCategory().name());
            break;
    }
}


@Override
public void message(PubNub pubnub, PNMessageResult message) {
    if (message.getMessage() != null) {
        String msg = message.getMessage().toString();
        //do what you want with the received message
    }
}

@Override
public void presence(PubNub pubnub, PNPresenceEventResult presence) {
  //not used in my case
}

  @Override
public void unsubscribeAndDisconnect() {
    pubnub.destroy();
}
```

And that it. Try to use their debug console in order to see if the delay maybe come from where you send the message.

Comment: It's totally right, I'm using old version of PubNub Android SDK. Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, the reconnect call doesn't count as any form of message? As in this is safe to simply loop until reconnect without using up any message usage allowance?